# Can you explicitly use an ancestor's virtual class method as a derived method?

Tags: c++, oop

Is it possible to explicitly use a distant ancestor's virtual function after it's already been overridden? Something similar to the following?

```
class A {
    virtual void task();
};

class B: public A {
    virtual void task() override;
};

class C: public B {
    virtual void task() = A::task; /* C++ doesn't like this */
};
```

I really don't want to have to re-implement something that's already been implemented. It seems it's technically possible because [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) uses a virtual table to point to class methods, so behind the scenes it should be able to put `A`'s method pointer in the table as if it were never overridden in the first place.

I do **NOT** want to do this:

```
class C: public B {
    virtual void task() {
        A::task();
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the function pure virtual?

Comment: @Anon, no, both functions have been implemented (in the header in my code, for debugging purposes)

Comment: This strongly suggests that `C` shouldn't be derived from `B`.

Comment: @Pete; I can understand where you're coming from with that, however `c` will use most of `B`'s other functions and variables. Since I need a base class mainly for pointers, would it be best to use multiple inheritance instead?

Comment: @Warpspace - that's a different question, and it requires different information than what's been provided here. So ask it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you want to use the method implementation in class `A` you can simply call it like `A::task()`.

That's a non-virtual call.

---

Regarding

> **”** c++ uses a virtual table to point to class methods

… no, that's not so, although that's the common implementation.

---

Regarding

> **”** I do **NOT** want to do this:
>
> ```
> class C: public B {
>   virtual void task() {
>       A::task();
>   }
> }
> ```

… that's the way to do it if you want `task` in class `C` to act as if it is the `A::task` implementation.

Comment: The pointer's always to the base class, so it has to be virtual

Comment: @Warpspace; Could you please elaborate a bit on what you mean? I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: I answered before you edited it, as per your first line. Sorry about that. I kind of thought the function table was part of the standard. I didn't realise it wasn't concrete

Comment: @Warpspace; The vtable is *almost* a standard feature. But it's not a good idea to mess with it, in C++ or other languages. I remember how some of the guys I'd help train in a consulting firm came to me for some advice. It was a Visual Basic project, that made me shudder already. They made every class a DLL, and it took a long time to load, why oh why? And, worse, they'd subclassed objects by fiddling with the vtable, and it crashed irregularly, could that possibly be connected? Well it got even worse when they came to management issues. But I think you get it.

Comment: I was never going to go behind C++'s back and do that. I was hoping there was some trick in the standard so I wouldn't have to have an extra function or level or indirection. Guess not

Answer (score 3):

You said:

> I do **NOT** want to do this:
>
> ```
> class C: public B {
>    virtual void task() {
>       A::task();
>    }
> };
> ```

I think this is the best solution given the current state of the standard.

Comment: You sure? It's a rather inelegant and inefficient solution given the way C++ works underneath. A `#define` with the function body is better than that.

Comment: @Warpspace, you can use a `#define` to make it look elegant but underneath it all, you'll need something like that.

Comment: "It's a rather [...] inefficient solution" - `A::task()` can be inlined if it's small enough to make sense and the implementation's visible to the compiler/linker at the right time, with zero overhead.

Comment: Is it possible to inline a virtual function? I thought that wasn't allowed

Comment: @Warpspace When called with explicit qualification, there's no virtual dispatch, so it's a function like any other. What prevents inlining is virtual dispatch with an unkown dynamic type, not just a function being virtual.

Comment: Unfortunately I will be using a pointer to the base class so the compiler won't know at compile-time what the object is. Otherwise I would not have made it virtual in the first place

Comment: IMO, it is silly to talk about efficiencies with hypothetical (`A`, `B`, `C`) classes.  Your question isn't really one about efficiency or syntax, but how to design classes in a hierarchy.  I find that most of the time when I am hung up on some piece of syntax or class structure that feels awkward, it is because my design is weak.  Focusing on my class design and architecture generally solves the problem.  A good book on OO design that I like is Eric Evans book ["Domain-Driven Design"](http://amzn.to/1NlgxEY).

Comment: @Warpspace: *"Unfortunately I will be using a pointer to the base class"* - I fear the penny's not dropped... you may call C::task using that pointer, and that call be virtually dispatched, but then the C::task function knows it needs to call A::task() and there's no pointer or reference to base involved - it's A::task that is inlined into C::task.  Net result: you have but one virtual dispatch, same as if you'd had some notation for changing the VDT for C as you postulate in the question.

Comment: I fear it is highly unlikely the compiler will respect my inline command for a function greater than a few lines. Nice theory, however if the inlining doesn't happen, then it's a double function call.

Comment: Anyway, my question has been answered. It is not possible. Pity. I will follow an alternative way, such as that mentioned

Comment: @Warpspace *"I fear it is highly unlikely the compiler will respect my inline command for a function greater than a few lines"* - if your function's large enough not to be inlined, it's usually also large enough that the overhead of a function call is relatively insignificant: they're strongly correlated.